# How to save response value to an variable in Tavern?

Tags: python, tavern

I am using `Tavern` to test my web server in `python3`. `Tavern` is to test the service based on a predefined `yaml` file. I have a backend API when response an auto generated id value to client. How can I test the auto-generated response? And how can I save the response to an variable and use it for other tests?

```
test_name: Test phonebook service

stages:
  - name: Make sure we can create new contact
    request:
     url: http://localhost:8080/v2/contact
     method: POST
     json:
      username: testUser
      first_name: first
      last_name: last
      email: test@email.com
      password: "123456"
      phone: "111111"
    response:
     status_code: 200
     body:
      contact_id: # This is auto generated id from backend
```

As the above example, it sends a POST request to the server and expect 200 status code in the response. But I don't know how to check the `contact_id` which is an integer generated by the backend. 
Also, I'd like to save the `contact_id` in a variable as the input for other APIs.

Answer (score 4):

It can be solved by using `save` in the response like:

```
response:
     status_code: 200
     headers:
      content-type: application/json
     save:
       body:
        contact_id: id
```

For [tavern >= 1.0](https://github.com/taverntesting/tavern/issues/495), use `json` instead of `body`:

```
response:
     status_code: 200
     headers:
      content-type: application/json
     save:
       json:
        contact_id: id
```

it will save the value of id from the response json object into a variable called `contact_id`. You can then reference this variable by `"{contact_id}"`, or `"{contact_id:d}"` if you want to typecast the variable as 'decimal integer'.

Comment: can I use this variable in a different test file ?